# Empty set NOT an element of a relation R={}?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We have the following sets:

M = {2,4,6,8,10,12,14}

N = {x ∈R|x>1 ∧ x is a divisor of 180 ∧ x<15}

L = {1,2,3,5,8,13,21}

and the following statement:

{} ∉ M ∩(N ×L)

Is the statement true or false?

Let R = M ∩(N ×L)

R = {}

So an empty set is an element of R={}?

Therefore the statement is false?

Comment: $R$ *is* the empty set.

Comment: Does $N\times L$ mean the Cartesian product? In that case, in what way does it make sense to intersect that with $M$?

Comment: @Arthur I don't know if it makes sense or not, obviously the answer would be an empty set just by looking at the sets given. However that is the question given to me.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes R yields an empty set. Is an empty set an element of a relation that is {} though?

Comment: If $R$ is **the** emptyset, by def the emptyset is empty: thus, it has **no** elements at all.

Comment: Conclusion: if $R = \emptyset$, then $\emptyset \notin R$.

Comment: $\{\}\notin M,$ therefore $\{\}\notin M\cap(N\times L\}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $R = \{\}, \{\} \not \in R$, because $\{\} \not \in \{\}$. Otherwise $R$ would not be empty, but $R$  would be $ = \{\{\}\}$.

Imagine sets as boxes:
$\{ \}$ is an empty box - a box with nothing in it.
$\{ \} \in A$ would mean that there is an empty box inside the box $A$ - but then $A$ is not empty, but contains something, namely a box.
$\{\{\}\}$ is not an empty box: It is a box that contains one thing, namely an empty box. And obviously a box with an (empty) box in it is not the same as an empty box.
So if $R = \{\}$, then $R$ is a box that contains nothing, not even an empty box, and therefore $\{\} \not \in \{\}$.